# Django Email Backend Setting Not Working

Tags: django, email, settings

I have a unit test with a test-specific settings file, which includes:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = '/my/file/path'
```

This wasn't working, so I dropped into the debugger to check the settings in the middle of running my test:

```
ipdb> from django.conf import settings
ipdb> settings.EMAIL_BACKEND
'django.core.mail.backends.locmem.EmailBackend'
ipdb> settings.EMAIL_FILE_PATH
'/my/file/path'
```

The file path setting worked, but the backend setting didn't!

Does anyone know why?

What else could I check/configure?

Is this something for a bug report?

Django 1.11

Comment: This is documented behaviour. Django replaces the regular email backend with a dummy one. [See the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#email-services).

Comment: I think this is the answer to the question. I ended up specifying the backend in the test itself - not using settings, which are overridden, but as a parameter for `send_email`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented behaviour. Django replaces the regular email backend with a dummy one. You then access the "sent" emails in your tests with `mail.outbox`. [See the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#email-services) for more info.

I believe you might be able to override the `EMAIL_BACKEND` for a single test or testcase with [`override_settings`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.override_settings)

```
from django.test import TestCase, override_settings

class MyTest(TestCase):
    @override_settings(EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend')
    def test_email(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this example to override the settings in your tests: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.SimpleTestCase.settings